# Massless $\phi^3$ theory in $d=6$ dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

I am asked to calculate renormalization for a massless $\phi^3$ theory in $d=6$ dimensional space using dimensional regularization. I'm having trouble finding the three-point vertex correction as one has to choose correct renormalization conditions.
Does anyone know where I can read about this problem?

Comment: Srednicki deals with this.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Minor point concerning retagging: I would say that the [tag:specific-reference] tag does not apply here cf. its [tag wiki](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-reference/info).

Comment: @Qmechanic: I would say that the OP is essentially asking "What is the canonical source for X?" with X = DimReg of massless $\phi^3$ theory in six dimensions, but if you think that is interpreting the OP too much, I will not defend my tagging to death. (The QFT tag though...)

Comment: @ACuriousMind I agree with Qmechanic, the tag is _very_ clearly not appropriate for this question, and accordingly I've removed it. A good guideline is that a question tagged with [tag:specific-reference] should have exactly one correct answer, so unless there is and will only ever be one source that gives the three-point vertex correction for massless $\phi^3$ theory, this is not one of those questions.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: In this case there could be a new canonical source tomorrow, and in such cases the specific-reference tag does not apply.

Comment: I seem to remember that Collins' book on renormalization goes into six-dimensional $\phi^3$ theory in great detail. I don't have the book available now, so I can't check exactly where to look.